# UPDATE leftjoin SET +/- problem

Tags: php, mysql

I want numbers to be added and subtracted according to one number entered in the table.

Here is my code:

```
  $uratio =  " 

    UPDATE teams
 LEFT JOIN games g1 ON (teams.ID = g1.op1ID)

SET ratio = ratio 
    + IF(g1.op1gamescore = 1 , g1.op1score, g1.op1score) 
 , ratio = ratio 
     - IF(g1.op1gamescore = 0, g1.op1score, g1.op1score) 

  WHERE g1.ID = '$_POST[id]'    ;   

     ";
      mysql_query($uratio) or die (mysql_error());


     $uratiob =  " 

    UPDATE teams 
    LEFT JOIN games g2 ON (teams.ID = g2.op2ID)
   SET ratio = ratio 
    + IF(g2.op2gamescore = 1, g2.op2score, g2.op2score) 
             , ratio = ratio 
    - IF(g2.op2gamescore = 0, g2.op2score, g2.op2score) 
   WHERE g2.ID = '$_POST[id]'    ;   

    ";
      mysql_query($uratiob) or die (mysql_error());
```

When op2gamescore = 1 it puts op1 with (negative sign) and op2 with (negative sign) op2 is fine but op1 not.

When op1gamescore = 1 it does the same.

It does correct math when op1 or op2 = 0 . But not when it equlas 1.

It does the correct math but op1 always ends with negative sign, why is that? Its like if it executes  - IF  and not + IF... ANY IDEAS?

Comment: You don't understand how IF works. It has 3 parameters, first is the condition, second is the value to return if the condition is true, third is the value to return if the condition is false. You return the same value whether the condition is true or false, so you're essentially just adding the score and subtracting it regardless of the conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

query 1:

```
UPDATE 
  teams 
LEFT JOIN 
  games 
ON
  teams.ID = games.op1ID
SET
  ratio = ratio + IF(games.op1gamescore = 1, games.op1score, -1 * games.op1score)
```

query 2:

```
UPDATE 
  teams 
LEFT JOIN 
  games 
ON
  teams.ID = games.op2ID
SET
  ratio = ratio + IF(games.op2gamescore = 1, games.op2score, -1 * games.op2score)
```

Comment: thnks! I stayed with the same code but used the (-1 *) to change the false condition

Comment: OK, but there's no need to set ratio twice in each query. Think it over some.